# Why is calling a function via a go plugin faster than calling the function directly

Tags: go, plugins, benchmarking

I wanted to benchmark go plugins to see what the performance difference was. So I made a main.go file with the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "strings"
)

// RandString generates and returns a random 50 character string
func RandString(n int) string {
    rand.Seed(int64(n))
    chars := []rune("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
        "0123456789")
    var b strings.Builder
    for i := 0; i < 50; i++ {
        b.WriteRune(chars[rand.Intn(len(chars))])
    }
    return b.String()
}
```

Then I turn this into a plugin.so file.

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o plugin.so main.go
```

Next I wrote two benchmark functions to test the performance of running the function inline vs running it via a go plugin.

```
// BenchmarkRandString tests generating a random string without a go plugin
func BenchmarkRandString(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        RandString(rand.Int())
    }
}

// BenchmarkPluginRandString tests generating a random string with a go plugin
func BenchmarkPluginRandString(b *testing.B) {
    plug, err := plugin.Open("./plugin.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    randString, err := plug.Lookup("RandString")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    randFunc, ok := randString.(func(n int) string)
    if !ok {
        panic("unexpected type from module symbol")
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        randFunc(rand.Int())
    }
}
```

As I would expect the plugin is a bit slower but not by much

> BenchmarkRandString-12                    128064              8600 ns/op
> BenchmarkPluginRandString-12              132007              8713 ns/op

Next I wanted to add 2 more benchmarks so I added another function to generate a random integer and built the plugin in the same way as before.

```
// RandInt uses math/rand to return a random integer
func RandInt() int {
    return rand.Int()
}
```

Then my new benchmark functions added above the previous two benchmark functions.

```
// BenchmarkRandInt tests math/rand for generating random integers without a go plugin
func BenchmarkRandInt(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        RandInt()
    }
}

// BenchmarkPluginRandInt uses a go plugin and tests math/rand for generating random integers
func BenchmarkPluginRandInt(b *testing.B) {
    plug, err := plugin.Open("./plugin.so")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    randInt, err := plug.Lookup("RandInt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    randFunc, ok := randInt.(func() int)
    if !ok {
        panic("unexpected type from module symbol")
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        randFunc()
    }
}
```

Now when I run the benchmark again I get the following result:

> BenchmarkRandInt-12                     77320668                13.2 ns/op
> BenchmarkPluginRandInt-12               76371756                13.9 ns/op
> BenchmarkRandString-12                    136243              8600 ns/op
> BenchmarkPluginRandString-12              142112              8564 ns/op

I can run the benchmark over and over again and BenchmarkRandString-12 is always a bit slower than BenchmarkPluginRandString-12 which is not what I would expect. Why is the go plugin function slightly faster when benchmarking like this?

I have a Github project with all of the source code I am using here: https://github.com/uberswe/goplugins/tree/4825172e011da9578553d113bac7933ca9ecd038

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What may be slower with a "plugin" function is its loading and the type assertion. Once you're done it, there should be no performance penalty compared to a function defined in your app.

Such small deviations may be the result of Go's internal memory management and garbage collection. For example if in your `main_test.go` file I move `BenchmarkPluginRandString()` above `BenchmarkRandString()`, then the benchmark result are "reversed": `BenchmarkRandString()` gets slightly slower.

To get rid of such non-deterministic factors, you may try to run the benchmarks isolated, e.g. run only one at a time with

```
go test -bench BenchmarkRandString
```

and

```
go test -bench BenchmarkPluginRandString
```

And do this multiple times, and calculate the average. This way there is no noticeable difference.